# How to debug merge handler code in sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: xconnect

I have written merge handler code for custom facet by seeing [sitecore documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/facets/facet-merge-handler.html). Searched a lot but did not find a way to debug code for  **MergingCalculatedFacetHandler** . Is there any way to do that?

Comment: is not clear for me what kind of code you try to debug. Can you add here you code and pipelines which you try to debug

Comment: I have updated my question. Is it clear now ? Or I have to update more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging of xConnect is no different from debugging any other website hosted in IIS.

1. Make sure that both dll with your changes and pdb files are copied to xConnect instance.
2. In Visual Studio click Debug > Attach to Process and attach to w3wp.exe. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200289/how-to-debug-code-in-sitecore) for more info. You might consider using [Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=thebread.AttachToAllTheThings) that simplifies attaching to IIS processes.
3. Add appropriate breakpoints to the merge handler in Visual Studio.
4. Run *xConnect* code that is supposed to invoke the handler, e.g. submit a contact/interaction using xConnect client.